How to create excel-like table in Tkinter which dynamically updates depending on user selection
I am very new to Python and Tkinter, currently I am trying to create my first project but ran into a roadblock. Will need some advice on how I can proceed.
I am trying to create a GUI that updates a table depending on the option that the user selected.
What I have done so far is create a Combobox for use to select if they want to view quarterly or monthly info.
Depending on the selection they choose, another Combobox will appear. In this combo box they can further decide on the specific month or quarter data to view.
After choosing on the specific month or quarter, a 7x4 grid table (originally blank) beside the comboboxes in the Window should be updated with Dataframe that was compiled in Pandas.
I am having trouble generating/creating a empty permanent 7x4 Table, with it being placed to the right of the combobox.
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from MarginCalculator import *
import MarginCalculator as MC
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def comboFunction(event): #Combo what to do when clicked on
    print(combo.get())
    if combo.get() == 'Quarterly': 
        combo_select = unqq_sort
    elif combo.get() == 'Monthly':
        combo_select = unqm_sort
    combomq = ttk.Combobox( #combo box to select q or m
        state='readonly',
        values=combo_select)
    combomq.place(x=50,y=100)
    combomq.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', outputFunction)

def outputFunction(event): #Combo what to do when clicked on the specific q or m
    print(comboFunction.combomq.get())

#--------------Data Setup---------------#
unqm_sort = unqm.tolist()
unqm_sort.sort()
unqq_sort = unqq.tolist()
unqq_sort.sort()

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('1400x800')
window.minsize(width= 1400, height= 800)


combo = ttk.Combobox(
    state='readonly',
    values = ['Monthly','Quarterly'])
combo.place(x=50,y=50)
combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', comboFunction)

window.mainloop()

I tried to create a simple test table, but am not sure how to move the table to a specific location within a window.
I have been googling for past 4 hours to no avail.
#--------------Output Table---------------#
# listdata = [
#     (1, 'cost', 'Margin', 22),
#     (2, 'aasd', 'bv',23),
#     (3, 'jf', 'kasd', 34)
# ]
# class Table:
#     def __init__(self,root):
#        for i in range(3):
#            for j in range (4):
#                self.e = Entry(root, width=22, fg='blue', font=('Arial',15,'bold'))
#                self.e.grid(row=i,column=j,sticky=tk.N)
#                self.e.insert(END, listdata[i][j])

# t = Table(window)


You can make Table inherit from tk.Frame, then you can put that frame anywhere you want.
